# C++ Class vector error, expression must have pointer type

Tags: c++

Currently learning some c++ and unsure why this is giving me "expression must have pointer type".

Mapp.hpp

```
class RouteMap
{
public:
    RouteMap();
    string getCurrent_();
    void StoreCity(string b);
private:
    std::vector<string>* cities();
    string current_; 
};
```

mapp.cpp

```
RouteMap::RouteMap(){}

string RouteMap::getCurrent_()
{
    return current_; 
}

void RouteMap::StoreCity(string b)
{
    cities->push_back(b); //Error 
}

std::vector<string> RouteMap::cities()
{
    return std::vector<string>();
}
```

I am attempting to have a vector Cities as a private member so that when I run the member function StoreCity(string x), it would push_back the specific string into Cities.

Comment: What is `cities` really? Is it a member *variable*? Or something else?

Comment: Also `cities` is a function of your class, you need to call it, so `cities->push_back` won't work

Comment: And I guess you have more errors regarding the `cities` *function*. What is its return type?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `cities()` returns a `std::vector<string>*` according to the declaration he's given us.

Comment: I would not use a pointer here: `std::vector<string>* cities();`

Comment: I believe it is a member variable, I am not entirely sure of the terminologies. I am not getting any errors besides the one I marked, is there something I missed entirely?

Comment: You made cities a function that returns an empty vector of strings.

Comment: @drescherjm I tried forgoing the pointers altogether like so, std::vector<string> cities(). And then just having cities.push_back but it still gives the same error.

Comment: `std::vector<string> cities();` is a function declaration. If you want a member variable remove the () part so like this `std::vector<string> cities;`. And also the remove implementation of the function: `std::vector<string> RouteMap::cities() { ... }`

Comment: It seems you're just guessing about things. That's not any good way to learn a language (program, spoken or otherwise written). Please [get a couple of good books about C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282), and start reading from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take a stab and say that the problem is `cities()` is a function and requires parenthesis:

```
cities()->push_back(b);
```

**Edit** Just found the implementation of `cities()` (silly me). You have another problem, and that is that your declaration and implementation don't match.

```
// declaration
std::vector<string>* cities();

// implementation. Notice the lack of a pointer type return
std::vector<string> RouteMap::cities()
{
    return std::vector<string>();
}
```

It's also weird that you're returning a new vector each time. You probably want a member variable:

```
class RouteMap
{
//...
private:
std::vector<string> my_cities;
//...
};
```

and then return the member variable from there:

```
std::vector<string>* RouteMap::cities()
{
    return &my_cities;
}
```

**Edit2:** It has come to my attention that you probably, while you could fix these things like this and get it working, the truth is that you probably don't mean for `cities()` to be a function at all. You probably mean for it to be a member variable instead:

```
class RouteMap
{
//...
private:
std::vector<string> cities;
//...
};
```

This requires no implementation, (aka `RouteMap::cities(){}`), and you can just use it inside any member function (because it's a private member) like current_.

Comment: The implementation of `cities` is in OPs question

Comment: Thank you, I feel like an idiot now, I tested that a while back but I guess i must have messed up somewhere else. Thank you again!

Comment: @UnholySheep Fixed... hopefully.

Comment: The OP most likely wanted `std::vector<string> cities;` and no function at all.

Comment: @drescherjm Added.